# Image viewer that can browse archives

Tags: images, image-viewer

Do you know any image viewer that is able to show images within archives?

So far I've been using xnview, which is quite buggy. But the problem is that it doesn't support archives :(

Comment: For what operating system?

Comment: for ms windows.

Comment: Just Google it. Here is a [Google search result](http://www.faststone.org/FSMaxView_ZIP_RAR.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a standalone program called "Fiew" which can apparently open images in zip and RAR archives.

I have, however, never used it myself.

[Link](http://fapplication.org/).

Alternatively you could open the archive with an archive viewer such as WinRAR and select and then open all images at once. Most image viewers will open only one window allowing you to navigate between the opened images (rather than opening a new window for each image).